# undefined variable when testing the store() using phpunit in laravel-4

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, phpunit

**SOLVED**

I have route that does a POST route towards store() in the controller.

I'm trying to test if the action is working properly.

Controller:

```
public function store() {
    $d= Input::json()->all();

    //May need to check here if authorized

    $foo= new Foo;
    $d = array();
    $d['name'] = $d['name'];
    $d['address'] = $d['address'];
    $d['nickname'] = $d['nickname'];



    if($foo->validate($d))
    {
        $new_foo= $foo->create($d);

        return Response::json(Foo::where('id','=',$new_foo->id)->first(),200);
    }
    else
    {
        return Response::json($foo->errors(),400);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to test this using a new class called FooTest.php

Here is the function i'm currently trying to do to make the check work:

```
 public function testFooCreation()
{

    $jsonString = '{"address": "82828282", "email": "test@gmail.com", "name":"Tester"}';

    $json = json_decode($jsonString);

    $this->client->request('POST', 'foo');

    $this->assertEquals($json, $this->client->getResponse());

}
```

when I run phpunit in my cmd, I get an error stating that "name" is undefined. I know i'm not actually passing anything to the request so I'm positive that nothing is actually being checked, but my question is how do I actually pass my json strings to check?

Everytime I put the $json inside the client request, it asks for an array, but when I convert my json string to an array, json_decode wants a string.

**UPDATE**

I was messing around with the passing of input data and I came across this:

```
 $input = [
        'name' => 'TESTNAME',
        'address' => '299 TESTville',
        'nickname' => 't'
        ];


     Input::replace($input);

     Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
        ->with(array('name' => Input::get('name'),
                     'address' => Input::get('address'),
                     'nickname' => Input::get('nickname')))
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);


     $response = $this->call('POST', 'foo', $input);
     $content = $response->getContent();
     $data = json_decode($response->getContent());
```

But whenever I run the test, i still get "name:undefined" It's still not passing the input i've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pass the input into a POST route from the test.

```
 public function testFooCreation(){

      $json = '{"name":"Bar", "address":"FooLand", "nickname":"foobar"}';

      $post = $this->action('POST', 'FooController@store', null, array(), array(), array(), $json);

      if($this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk()) == true && $this->assertResponseStatus(201)){

      echo "Test passed";
      }

 }
```

Turns out that in order for me to actually pass input into the controller through test POST, I have to pass it through the 7th parameter.

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

```
$d= Input::json()->all();
```

The above statement gets Input in $d.

```
$d = array();
```

Now the last statement again initialises $d as an **empty new array**.

So there is no: $['name'] . Hence, Undefined.

I think, that's the problem with the above code.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Correct. I know that haha. My question isn't actually why is my 'name' undefined. My question is how to actually test it using phpunit. I want to pass in data using my test function for the store() and check if it actually works.

Comment: Check my update. Maybe my question will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

of course you get an error , just look at your code

```
$aInputs = Input::json()->all();

    //May need to check here if authorized

    $foo= new Foo;
    $d = array();
    $d['name'] = $d['name'];
    $d['address'] = $d['address'];
    $d['nickname'] = $d['nickname'];
```

your assigning the array to it self, which is empty

Comment: why did you open another question, the problem is the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857763/testing-a-post-using-phpunit-in-laravel-4/24857916#24857916

Comment: Yes I clarified that in my answer that of course I'm getting an error. My question is how do I actually do a test that puts in example inputs to check whether or not the store() is doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I opened another question because this one was a bit more specific in terms of the process I'm looking for. The other question seemed to be a bit sloppy.